# Getting equal strings out of a jagged array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a jagged array, add a whole lot of technical terms and definitions to it, then print out a random term along with it's corresponding definition.

Here is my code, it's close to working, but just not quite there.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>GLOSSARY</title>
</head>

<body>

<script> 

window.onload = function(){

    function randomRange(l,h){
        var range = (h-l);
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*range);
        if (random === 0){random+=1;}
        return l+random;
    }

    document.write("<h1> GLOSSARY </h1>"); 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";

    var a = [[],[]]; 
    a.push('hobo', 'person who drinks and drifts'); 
    a.push('google', 'Search Company'); 
    a.push('Stack Overflow', 'smart dudes who answer stuff'); 

    var r = randomRange(0, a.length);
    document.writeln(a[r],[r]);

};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create an array of objects? eg:

```
var a = [];
a.push({ name: 'hobo', desc: 'person who drinks and drifts' }); 
a.push({ name: 'google', desc: 'Search Company' }); 
a.push({ name: 'Stack Overflow', desc: 'smart dudes who answer stuff' });
```

Then you can reference the description of the 3rd item as `a[2].desc` for example.

Comment: Why not `[{...},{...},{...}]`?

Comment: yeah that seems to work. 

@JanDvorak, I've never used javascript before so this is all I could think up.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the contents of your array a I think you'll find a.push isn't doing what you think it does.

You probably mean this

```
var a = [];
a.push(['hobo', 'person who drinkd and drifts'])
```

Comment: i thought it was just putting a term and a definition into the array? seems to be working now anyhow ..

Answer (score 0):

Others have given you good replies. I'd go with a hash (associative array) and use the first terms as keys, ie. "google", "hobo" and work that way.. But given your current structure, you can fix it by just doing this.

```
var a = []; 
a.push(['hobo', 'person who drinks and drifts']); 
a.push(['google', 'Search Company']); 
a.push(['Stack Overflow', 'smart dudes who answer stuff']); 

var r = randomRange(0, a.length);
document.writeln(a[r][0],a[r][1]);
```